# I want to make a function in C that prints a 2D array

Tags: arrays, c, function, multidimensional-array, printf

I know how to print a 2D array without using a function (using nested for loops), but how would I implement a fuction that prints it.

This is what I tried

```
int print_matrix(int arr[M][N])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) 
        {
            printf("{%i}",arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: use [C11 6.7.6.3p20 VLA](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p20): `int print_matrix(int M, int N, int arr[M][N]) { ... }` and call it like `int a[10][3] = {42}; print_matrix(10, 3, a);`

Comment: "We" didn't. And the code you posted *absolutely* didn't. There is no `M` nor `N` defined.

Comment: @pmg: In contrast to C99, C11 has demoted VLAs to an optional feature. Compliant compilers are no longer required to implement them. For example, the Microsoft compiler does not implement them.

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
int print_matrix(int M, int N, int arr[M][N])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) 
        {
            printf("{%i}",arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int N = 4;
   int M = 4;
   //...
   int arr[M][N];
   //...
    print_matrix(M, N, arr);
}
```

Comment: I get "use of undeclared identifier 'M' " and "use of undeclared identifier 'N' " errors when I compile.

Comment: It compiles fine [here](https://www.godbolt.org/z/n1heMvcfx), maybe you have a non conformant compiler.

Comment: I tried to compile it again after restarting my laptop and for some reason it worked , thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `int M, int N` to the function:

```
int print_matrix(int M, int N, int arr[M][N])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) 
        {
            printf("{%i}",arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

how to call your fucntion:

```
int M = 5;
int N = 4;
//define your array
int arr[M][N];

print_matrix(M, N, arr)
```